# How to send custom list view selected item id through checkbok

Tags: android

I am very new in android.I want to send list item id through checkbox.I have custom list view with a checkbox.I want to send when checkbox click, selected id send those id through array to my mysql database.but I don't understand how to do that.

> custom row

```
private Activity activity;
private List<TestAddData> Items;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomTestAdd(Activity activity, List<TestAddData> items) {
    this.activity = activity;
    Items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return Items.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_test_add, null,true);

    TextView testname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.testname);
    CheckBox testid = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.testid);

    //getting data
    TestAddData m = Items.get(position);

    //set data
    testname.setText(m.getTestName());

    return convertView;
}
```

this class extends BaseAdapter..

> data save class

```
private int testid;
private String testName;
private boolean isSelected;
public TestAddData(){}

public int getTestid() {
    return testid;
}

public void setTestid(int testid) {
    this.testid = testid;
}

public String getTestName() {
    return testName;
}

public void setTestName(String testName) {
    this.testName = testName;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    isSelected = selected;
}

public TestAddData(int testid, String testName, boolean isSelected) {
    this.testid = testid;
    this.testName = testName;
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}
```

I want to pass this test id via checkbox..

> list activity

```
class task2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        findViewById(R.id.pb).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String url_select = "http://mybusket.com/webapi/dgc/dgcbcl/get_all_patient.php";

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url_select);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        try {
            httpGet.setURI(new URI(url_select));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            // read content
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        try {
            lv2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.testList);
            lv2.setAdapter(customTestAdd);
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("pat");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                TestAddData patientData = new TestAddData();
                patientData.setTestName(obj.getString("name"));
                patientData.setTestid(obj.getInt("patid"));

                testLists.add(patientData);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        findViewById(R.id.pb).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a PHP tag here, but apparently no PHP or MySQL code? That seems to be missing. There's also a *ton* of Java code here that seems largely unrelated to your database problem.

Comment: @tadman Sorry...my mistake...This is android project.

Comment: That much was clear. What isn't is how MySQL factors in.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I see you are not able to get which checkbox is selected, I have worked on a similar issue, so before you worry about submitting data to the database, first get the value of the checkbox

you need an `array` in your TestAddData to hold your checked boxes, in my case I created an array of type `String` and passed the `text of the checkbox`, because getting an id would be tedious.

**Note: useing an array because it's possible to check many checkboxes**

here is my code inside the `getView()` method

```
final CheckBox testId= (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxS);
cb.setText(stringList.get(i));

testId.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (b){ //checked

            TestAddData.checkedboxes[i]=testId.getText().toString();
        }else { //unchecked
            // pass an empty value
            TestAddData.checkedboxes[i] = "";
        }

    }

});
```

now on every box checked, its text will be added to the array in TestAppData, whenever you want to submit data to the data base, just extract the data from the array.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Activity activity;
private List<TestAddData> Items;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomTestAdd(Activity activity, List<TestAddData> items) {
    this.activity = activity;
    Items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return Items.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_test_add, null,true);

    TextView testname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.testname);
    CheckBox testid = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.testid);

testid.setTag(position);
testid.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
int pos=(int)buttonView.getTag();
testid.setChecked(isChecked);
int id=Items.get(pos).id;


       }
   }
);

    //getting data
    TestAddData m = Items.get(position);

    //set data
    testname.setText(m.getTestName());

    return convertView;
}
```